# Jquery plugin bind change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I just created a `selectbox` plugin.It is very simple and I am trying to modify it.

Actually what it is doing is to hide the select and add some `ul,li` after that `select`.

Say that I have these options available

```
<select id="test">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

Now I can do

```
$("#test").selectBox(); //to make it my selectBox
```

I have setter and getter options

```
$("#test").selectBox("changeValue",["changed option",index]);
```

On my plugin I am using methods ..

```
var methods = {

init :function(options){},

changeValue:function(value){

//some code to change the value ...

}

};
```

I can change the value ,but how can I catch the `change` event?

`change` means that a change in select or `ul,li`

What I really need is

```
$("#test").selectBox(); //initialise

$("#test").change(function(){ //attach change event

//my codes.....

});
```

or

```
$("#test").selectBox({
onChange : function(){

console.log("changed....");

}


});
```

Hope that the question is clear now.
Thank you.

**EDIT : HERE IS THE FIDDLE link http://jsfiddle.net/jitheshkt/rBjqq/3/
Please note that i am not a expert on this and just trying to make it.**

**Edit : i wrote events inside the each function ,so i think that that will be the problem. i changed it and working well **

Comment: Have a look at [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). You can fire an event on the matched element in your `changeValue` method, and listen for it on that element.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Thanks..looks promising one ...but could you please help me little more about this ?

Comment: Could you plz show what your initialization code is doing to original select element.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko select the select element,add a `input text`,`ul,li` .its simple ... i am really dare to show my code [its too ugly] :)

Comment: @Garbage I just wonder if you are simply hiding it or detaching some way. :)

Comment: I am hiding the select element ...i tried to use `.trigger()` ,but it changing the whole select element on the page ...

Comment: I updated the question with fiddle link @yury

Comment: Please check this link. http://jsfiddle.net/rBjqq/7/

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$("#test").on('change',function(){ 
    // Write  your code here.
});
```

For Older version of jQuery Use this

```
$("#test").change(function() {
    console.log('HI');
});
```

This should work as it is.

Comment: Sorry ...its not working ...also there is no need to use `on`

Comment: Which version on jQuery you are using? If you are using older version then please do respective change. I'll edit my code. Same thing is working for me. I'm also using the same plugin.

Comment: yes you are right ..it will work..but here its not working ..this is because the event is not getting fired ..

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle link. Then I can show you the working of it. I'm telling this coz I'm using the same thing and its working for me.

Comment: +1 for ur helping mentality .sure bro ,i updated the question with fiddle link ...thank you for helping me...

Comment: Sorry for the delay I was busy with my stuff.. Here is the link Please check. http://jsfiddle.net/rBjqq/7/

Comment: No trouble bro ,but vins its not the correct answer for the question,we can easily bind an event to an element with `bind` or `live` or `on` ,normally we will use `on` in the case of elements that which are added after creating the dom creation.the correct answer was `.trigger()` which is pointed by `james`,thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are setting the value using [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method. The change event doesn't trigger if you are changing the value using jQuery API/JavaScript, so you have to trigger it manually, like this:

```
$('#test').change()
```

or

```
$('#test').trigger('change');
```

I hope that would do the trick!!

Comment: yes it will work ...but it changes the whole select box ...please see the fiddle ..

Answer (score 1):

You can depend on the original select box change rather than your customized select box.

When you select an li item, you update the corresponding value in original selectbox so that change get's fired..

Comment: yes when i select a li item it will change the selected item ,but the event is not getting fired...